# Back to top button extends animation duration with every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I built a back to the top button (CSS Animation, jQuery Waypoint Plugin for adding classes and the back to top script), which is nearly working. However, somehow it extends the animation process when you use it more than once with every new click, so the window is stucked on the very top, even when the animation should be finished. I don't know why this is happening and I already tried some tutorials and jQuery snippets for the back to the top button with no success.

May someone have a look at my fiddle, where you can inspect the described behaviour to give me further instructions how to fix this or why this is happening?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rshpqstf/2/

Javascript

```
 /* Bottom Bar Behaviour */
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var waypoints = jQuery('.footer').waypoint({
   handler: function(direction) {
     jQuery('.frame-bottom_down span').toggleClass('test', direction === 'down');
     jQuery('.frame-bottom_up span').toggleClass('test2', direction ==='down');
     jQuery('.js-frame-bottom, .frame-bottom_ttl').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 700);
      return false;
      })
    },
    offset: '100%'
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
 <div class="main-placeholder"></div>
 <div class="footer"></div>
<div class="frame-bottom" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-frame-bottom frame-bottom_ttl">
    <p class="frame-bottom_down">
        <span>S</span><span>C</span><span>R</span><span>O</span><span>L</span><span>L</span>
        <span>D</span><span>O</span><span>W</span><span>N</span>
        </p>
     <p class="frame-bottom_up">
         <span>P</span><span>A</span><span>G</span><span>E</span>
         <span>U</span><span>P</span>
         </p>
     </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
 body {
 background: #fff;
}

.main-placeholder {
 height:2000px;
 width: 100%;
 }

.frame-bottom {
 z-index: 2000;
 height: 50px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 color: #979797;
 background-color: #333;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: .05em;
 line-height: 3.3;
 }

.frame-bottom_ttl {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 cursor: default;
 }

 .frame-bottom_up, .frame-bottom_down {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  }

 .frame-bottom_down span, .frame-bottom_up span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  }

 .frame-bottom_down span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
 }

 .frame-bottom_down span.test {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5);
 }

 .frame-bottom_up span {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
 }

 .frame-bottom_up span.test2 {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
 }

 .frame-bottom_down span.test:nth-child(1) { transition-delay: 0s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span.test:nth-child(2) { transition-delay: 0.02s;}
 .frame-bottom_down span.test:nth-child(3) { transition-delay: 0.04s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span.test:nth-child(4) { transition-delay: 0.06s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span.test:nth-child(5) { transition-delay: 0.08s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span.test:nth-child(6) { transition-delay: 0.1s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span.test:nth-child(7) { transition-delay: 0.12s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span.test:nth-child(8) { transition-delay: 0.14s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span.test:nth-child(9) { transition-delay: 0.16s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span.test:nth-child(10) { transition-delay: 0.18s; }

 .frame-bottom_up span.test2:nth-child(1) { transition-delay: .2s; }
 .frame-bottom_up span.test2:nth-child(2) { transition-delay: 0.22s; }
 .frame-bottom_up span.test2:nth-child(3) { transition-delay: 0.24s; }
 .frame-bottom_up span.test2:nth-child(4) { transition-delay: 0.26s; }
 .frame-bottom_up span.test2:nth-child(5) { transition-delay: 0.28s; }
 .frame-bottom_up span.test2:nth-child(6) { transition-delay: .3s; }


 .frame-bottom_down span:nth-child(1) { transition-delay: 0.12s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span:nth-child(2) { transition-delay: 0.14s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span:nth-child(3) { transition-delay: 0.16s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span:nth-child(4) { transition-delay: 0.18s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span:nth-child(5) { transition-delay: .2s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span:nth-child(6) { transition-delay: .22s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span:nth-child(7) { transition-delay: 0.24s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span:nth-child(8) { transition-delay: 0.26s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span:nth-child(9) { transition-delay: 0.28s; }
 .frame-bottom_down span:nth-child(10) { transition-delay: .3s; }

 .frame-bottom_up span:nth-child(1) { transition-delay: 0s; }
 .frame-bottom_up span:nth-child(2) { transition-delay: 0.02s; }
 .frame-bottom_up span:nth-child(3) { transition-delay: 0.04s; }
 .frame-bottom_up span:nth-child(4) { transition-delay: 0.06s; }
 .frame-bottom_up span:nth-child(5) { transition-delay: 0.08s; }
 .frame-bottom_up span:nth-child(6) { transition-delay: 0.1s; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add wheel event handler to `stop` animation when wheel scrolling happened.

```
jQuery('.main-placeholder').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
//console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);
console.log(event);
jQuery('html, body').stop(true);
});
```

Please have a look the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rshpqstf/3/

Comment: Hey Joey, many thanks for your help! May you confirm that this is also working on firefox for you? While it seems to work in safari & chrome, I can't get the desired result on firefox (official + nightly). I've also noticed that the button is always clickable when you've clicked it once, so I added an if statement to the jQuery. But still I don't have success on firefox. Here is my fiddle with your idea (thanks again!) and the new if statement:

https://jsfiddle.net/rshpqstf/4/

Comment: Hi , you just need to add "DOMMouseScroll" event for firefox:
   window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    //console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);
  
    jQuery('html, body').stop(true);
});

Comment: Damn, you know what? You rock! I've tried to solve this about three hours now. Okay, I am very new to javascript/jQuery, but I guess, without your help, it would have taken days to solve this. In the next step I will check the script regarding performance etc. But, yes, everything you've said, was right. Thank you very much, Joey! :)